# Please I was trying to connect my project to a database but I got an error: the name ‘textbox’ does not exist in the current context

Tags: html, css, webforms

How do I connect my project to a live database, because when I tried to connect to my database, I got an error which stated that: **the name ‘textbox’ does not exist in the current context** ?
How do I correct this error, please?

This is my aspx.cs code for the connection which I tried to use and it gave me the error

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:Users SOLO Desktop DesHomeWeb App_Data Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
    }


protected void btn3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into signup " + " (fname)values(@fname)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textbox.text);
    }
}
```

This is the HTML code for the textbox in my aspx codding window

```
<td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="textbox1" id="textbox" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET web forms, I believe that you will need to use the asp:TextBox control rather than the html input element as shown below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox placeholder="First Name" ID="textbox" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button id="btn3" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="btn3_click" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

Assuming that your SQL Server Express database is named "Database.mdf" and it is located in the App_Data folder of your solution, you can use the |DataDirectory| variable instead of the physical path to your database file. ASP.NET will automatically substitute the file path to the App_Data directory for the |DataDirectory| variable when it opens the connection to the database. Note, that you will need to escape the backslash character by using double backslash \ in your connection string:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;User Instance=True";
```

Comment: ok. that was helpful. how about button used to insert data into the database? am I also going to use asp button control?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've modified my answer to include a button control.

Comment: Can you also help me check my connection string? its not connecting..I don't know if it is due to spaces given in the connection string

Comment: I updated my answer to include changes to the connection string, hopefully that will fix the database connection issue.